Let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $m^{1 / 3}=n+l$,
Let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $m^{1 / 3}=n+l$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $0<l<1 / 2024$. What is the value of $n$ ?
how to even begin with , the answer is given 26 but no  idea to begin with

I would search the numbers of the form $m=k^3+1$.  That gives the desired result quickly.

how u think that

The optimum must be of the fork $k^3+1$ because those numbers give the smallest positive fractional parts of the $3$ rd root.

but we want smallest n

Hence the search.  I suppose one could do it analytically, but I think that would be a whole lot slower.  The search just takes seconds.

The Laurent series for $\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}$ is $x+\frac 1{3x^2}-\frac 1{9x^5}\cdots$, so you just need $\frac 1{3x^2}$ to be small enough.  Again, working out that series took longer than the search did.  Well, it's fast if you use WA

@lulu To be fair , I assume you found $n=26$ per computer , so the argument that brute force is faster is doubtful.

@Peter  Agreed.  The series expansion can be done by hand.

analytic approach is best

Get a lower bound on the value of the integer $m-n^3$

Should $n$ be 19?

$6860^{\frac{1}{3}}=19.00092...<19+\frac{1}{1024}$

@Paul problem asked for $\frac 1{2024}$.

Ah right, saw the 24 on the end and assumed it was $2^{10}$. Phones, old eyes...

To summarize the discussion in the comments:
The solution must be of the form $m=k^3+1$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$.
Pf: If $m$ is the solution, let $k^3$ be the greatest perfect cube less than $m$.  Then $m=k^3+r$ for some $r\in \mathbb N$.  But $k<\sqrt[3]{k^3+1}<\sqrt[3]{k^3+r}<k+1$ if $r>1$ contradicting minimality, so $r$ must be $1$.
Now it's just a simple matter of a search.
As an alternative, which can be done by hand, we can look at the series expansion near $x=\infty$ $$(1+x^3)^{1/3}=x+\frac 1{3x^2}-\frac 1{9x^5}+\frac 5{81x^8}+O\left(\frac 1{x^{11}}\right)$$
for an analytic solution.  Slower, of course, but it can be done by hand

Side note:  Why is $\sqrt[3] {f(x)}$ formatting so poorly?  I am writing \sqrt[3] {f(x)}, which I have used many times before without a problem.

Is this a browser issue?  What I'm seeing:  the $3$ in the cube root is invisible, as the radical symbol crosses through it. And the top of the radical is annoyingly broken.  If someone can fix this, I'd be grateful.  And more so if they could explain my formatting error.

every thing is fine

You mean, it looks good on your browser?  That's good to know.  I'm using the current version of Chrome...surprised it has this bug.

yes everything is fine, i am goint to upload more fancy questions.

$m-n^3=l(3n^2+3nl+l^2) = k$ an integer and $3n^2+3nl+l^2 =\frac{k}{l} > 2^{10}k$. Now check the cases k = 1, 2, 3,.. and solve for $n$. You can stop at $k = 1$ where $n = 19$.

Should be 2024 not $2^{10}$. In which case $k=2$ and $n=26$
